# Spring Boot Maven/Gradle plugin: bootRun task generates very long classpath?

Tags: java, gradle, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

### Components

- Spring Boot 1.4.3 (and have also tried with Spring Boot 1.5 RC1)
- Java 1.8.0_112 on Mac OS Sierra
- Gradle 3.3 / Maven 3.3.9
- Simple Java web application configured with Spring Boot Gradle plugin (Same issue appears to be applicable to the Spring Boot Maven plugin as well)

### Problem

Attempting to run the application via the likes of `gradlew clean build bootRun` or simply `gradlew bootRun` shows that the gradle/java process exits/crashes miserably without a hint. No further errors or logs are displayed other than:

"/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java finished with non-zero exit value 1".

Running `gradlew bootRun --debug` however shows that the BootRun (an extension of Gradle's JavaExec) task seems to want to generate a VERY VERY VERY long Classpath entry that ultimately bombs the Java process.

The Spring Boot documentation specifies:

> To run a project in place without building a jar first you can use the “bootRun” task

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-gradle-running-applications

But it doesn't seem like this method can work if the plugin is to generate such long classpaths.

### Reproduce

This project here may demonstrate the issue:

https://github.com/apereo/cas-gradle-overlay-template

In the `cas/build.gradle` file, one could add a dependency to observe the behavior:

`compile "org.apereo.cas:cas-server-support-json-service-registry:${project.'cas.version'}"`

### Diagnosis

The project contains the following dependency:

`dependencies {
    compile "somewhere:something:somehow@war"
}`

This presents no issues at all to `bootRun`; however when any other compile/runtime dependency is added to the project, all dependencies transitive or otherwise are added to the classpath for `bootRun` to execute.

I did also try creating a "pathing" JAR with hopes that the plugin/Java might simply use the `Class-Path` entry in that JAR's manifest to run the web application and the classpath entry passed to the java command would be shortened as such. However, that did not make a single difference and java simply crashed again.

Note that running the web application as an executable jar with `java -jar app.war` works perfectly fine with all dependencies, etc.

Have others run into similar issues?

Comment: Pathing JAR should fix the problem of running it in windows. I didn't see the pathing JAR config in your repo.

Comment: As is pointed out in the description of the question, this has nothing to do with Windows.